# Lubuntu: Error messaging when trying to add a SAMBA Printer

Tags: lubuntu, printing, samba

> "unfortunately the smbclient you were searching for could not be
>   found. Please see this website for more information" (The website is
>   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/).

This is the message when trying to add a SAMBA printer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry just being silly.

Worked it out.  Just

```
sudo apt-get install smbclient
```

and then when it complains about python3-smbc do:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-smbc
```

Comment: well done; thanks for posting; newer versions of ubuntu accept `sudo apt install ..` saves the typing!